# Assigning permissions for sysmail_update_account_sp

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, permissions, database-mail, signature

I have a Microsoft SQL Server 2014. The mail system is configured via DBMail and
there is one stored proc in main web app (having its own database) which executes msdb's *sysmail_update_account_sp* by selecting the appropriate profile using *msdb.dbo.sysmail_account*.

The problem I am facing is the web application has a SQL login and I want to switch context and execute *sysmail_update_account_sp*.

```
EXEC AS USER = @UserName

    SET @AccountNr = ( SELECT TOP 1 account_id FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_account WHERE name = @DatabaseName ORDER BY account_id )

    IF @AccountNr > 0

    EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sysmail_update_account_sp
                @account_id = @AccountNr
                , @email_address = @ParamSMTPFrom
                , @account_name = @DatabaseName
                , @display_name = @DatabaseName
                , @replyto_address = @ParamSMTPFrom
                , @description = @EmailAccountDescription
                , @mailserver_name = @ParamWebAppSmtpServer
                --[ , [ @mailserver_type = ] 'server_type' ] 'optional only SMTP supported'
                , @port = @ParamWebAppSMTPPort
                , @username = @ParamWebAppSMTPUser
                , @password = @ParamWebAppSMTPPwd
                , @use_default_credentials = 0 -- we will always have nor domain credientials @DefaultCredentials
                --use account name and password
                --not databse credentials
                , @enable_ssl = @SSL -- bit 1 for use ssl
REVERT
```

Error occurring is:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal
>   "SERVERNAME\dbMailUser" does not exist, this type of principal cannot
>   be impersonated, or you do not have permission

Things I checked:

1. SERVERNAME\dbMailUser has DatabaseMailUserRole permission in msdb currently.
2. If I add the executing stored proc user (from web app) as sysadmin,I don't have to switch or anything. But I want to limit the permission to it's minimum.

How can I execute as a different user (SQL or Windows Login) by switching context properly? The current SQL login is a database owner.

The requirement is the login should be able to configure DBMail from a stored procedure and able to send mails (the DatabaseMailUserRole), without it being in the sysadmin role.

Am I in the right direction, regarding my understanding of how DBMail configuration works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request is very similar to, if not the same as, another question on here (DBA.StackExchange) regarding the need for very granular elevated permissions. I provided working code in my answer, and that could be used here as well:

[What minimum permissions do I need to provide to a user so that it can check the status of SQL Server Agent Service?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/what-minimum-permissions-do-i-need-to-provide-to-a-user-so-that-it-can-check-the/103275#103275)

The overall concept is the same: give the Stored Procedure itself the required permission by being associated (via the Certificate) with a Login that has the proper permission. The only difference would be that instead of granting `VIEW SERVER STATE TO [MrDoStuff]`, you would probably just add `[MrDoStuff]` to the `sysadmin` fixed server-level role.

One difference, though, between this question and the "What minimum permissions..." question is that the other question simply needed access to a DMV and not to any code objects outside of the code being signed. It just so happens that signatures do not, by default, transfer to code called by the signed code. But there is a way of allowing this to happen: counter-sign the external code being called. Counter-signing allows code executed by signed-code to transfer the signature without actually being signed itself (and so the external code cannot be called independently). Counter signing is handled by the same [ADD SIGNATURE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181700.aspx) function that was used to sign the initial Stored Procedure:

1. Restore the Certificate into the `[msdb]` database
2. Counter-sign the `dbo.sysmail_update_account_sp` Stored Procedure

Continuing the example code from that other answer, the additional steps should be:

```sql
USE [msdb];

CREATE CERTIFICATE [DoStuffCert]
    FROM FILE = 'C:\temp\ViewSqlAgentStatus.CER'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (
        FILE = 'C:\temp\ViewSqlAgentStatus.PVK',
        DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'DontStartNoneWontBeNone',
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'W0rdUp,Yo!'
    );

ADD COUNTER SIGNATURE TO dbo.sysmail_update_account_sp
    BY CERTIFICATE [DoStuffCert] WITH PASSWORD = 'W0rdUp,Yo!';
```

It is possible that if `sysmail_update_account_sp` executes any stored procedures, then they might also need to be counter-signed.

Comment: Hi @srutzky, I followed the steps as you mentioned and added the user to sysadmin role, So when I execute the stored proc now I am getting :- User does not have permission to perform this action.(at the place where I call msdb update function for DbMail configuration). I believe I don't have to switch context because that was the whole point of going via certificate route ( the created login is mapped to msdb and database under question) having sysadmin role. Why should that error be appearing in that case?

Comment: @RohithNair Correct, you should not need the `EXECUTE AS` at all using this approach. I believe the issue is the need for a counter signature. I have updated my answer by adding info starting with "One difference...". Please let me know how that works. If not, then it might just be that one remaining step is to create a User in `msdb` from the `[MrDoStuff]` Login. But let's try just this next piece by itself first.

Comment: I added the counter signature and it started working. I didn't add the user as sysadmin but gave permissions to alter settings, control server and alter any credential , because when I gave sysadmin I couldn't see user token of certificate being propagated to inner stored procs in msdb

Comment: @RohithNair That is perfect. There is no reason to give more permissions than is necessary to complete the desired tasks. So if you can get away without putting the Login into the `sysadmin` role, then great. Glad it is working for you :).

Comment: just to add if the mail you are sending l is having attachments then the above said method will fail, it requires access permissions using sysadmin role

Comment: @RohithNair To clarify, you mean that the method I described here does work when attachments are involved, but only after adding the Certificate-based Login to the `sysadmin` fixed server role, correct? If yes, then I will update my answer to include that detail. Thanks.

Comment: yes, I had to make the login a sysadmin which kind of sadly defeated the purpose, all the way going through creating certificates, If its a sysadmin role there is indeed no need of signed certificate because you are the god on the system right?

Comment: @RohithNair No, putting the Login into the `sysadmin` server role did _not_ defeat the purpose of creating the Certificate in any way. There is no way to connect as the Certificate-based Login or Impersonate it via `EXECUTE AS`. It is just a container for permissions. The permissions still needs to be assigned to a module so that the module can inherit the permission(s). This is still very secure, much more than Impersonation. It just means you don't need the Certificate created in `msdb`, and no need to counter sign, as the Login should be able to execute across database boundaries.

Comment: @strutzky Last time I checked when I put MrDoStuff to sysadmin role, the   certificate  token were not  propagated to inner stored procs in msdb. That is why I kept to alter settings, control server and alter any credential  (mentioned in my second comment). But then suddenly I recognised mail with attachments were failing and had to revert back the original login to sysadmin .  I will check again and get back to you with more clarity.

Comment: @RohithNair If it turns out that you do, in fact, still need the Certificate in `msdb` so that the other proc can be counter-signed, then this is still a far better (i.e. more secure) approach than Impersonation. Nobody will ever be able to hijack the Certificate-based Login / User or even your stored procedure to use those permissions in a way that you did not specifically intend.

Comment: I agree with you, but in a multi database scenario, if we make a login sysadmin , he as the rights to view or edit other databases right [I am not talking about MrDoStuff login]  but the main login for database? Not talking about sending mails alone.

Comment: @RohithNair I am confused now. I did not think we were talking about the actual app Login, just the Certificate-based Login. I asked above if you had meant that the Certificate-based Login was the one that needed to be in `sysadmin` and you said "yes". If you are now saying that it is the actual Login that the app uses, that is different. Also, if the question is now about permissions needed for Attachments, that is a new question (related to this one, but different) as Database Mail runs asynchronously via Service Broker, so a separate process needs to be accounted for.

Comment: @RohithNair Also, just saw this ( http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65217/problem-sending-an-attachment-using-dbo-sp-send-dbmail ) and it could simply be that you need to add the appropriate NTFS permission to the service account running Service Broker.

Answer (score 0):

[sysmail_update_account_sp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188381.aspx) requires membership in the sysadmin fixed server role. This means that `DatabaseMailUserRole` or any other msdb fixed database role is not enough.

Using `EXECUTE AS LOGIN` to impersonate a sysadmin login from your non-privileged login completely defeats the purpose of using a non-privileged user, as it can escalate permissions at any time (requires `IMPERSONATE` permissions).

I would recommend to wrap the code you have to execute in a stored procedure and the sign it with a certificate. The technique is discussed a lenght on [Erland Sommarskog's blog](http://www.sommarskog.se/grantperm.html). That page goes into deep details of all the possible solutions, with downsides and upsides to each of them.