# Minimum permissions required for mail attachment in DbMail

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-mail

I know that SQL DbMail requires for attaching, a windows login or a sysadmin privilege is required.

This is somewhat similar to  [minimum dbMail permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/120519/assigning-permissions-for-running-sysmail-update-account-sp/120528#120528) which was asked by me at an earlier point.

I want to understand whether without sysadmin what is the minimum privilege required for attaching files.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in the TechNet article on [`sp_send_dbmail`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307%28v=sql.110%29.aspx):

> Execute permissions for **sp_send_dbmail** default to all members of the
>   **DatabaseMailUser** database role in the **msdb** database. However, when the
>   user sending the message does not have permission to use the profile
>   for the request, **sp_send_dbmail** returns an error and does not send the
>   message.

As for attachments, the SQL Server service account (the actual Windows/AD account that the SQL Server process runs on) is also going to need read access to the actual folder where the file is stored.